# Error inflating class fragment, Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin

I have an error on inflating the fragment into a layout.
The IDE I am working with is **Xamarin**, which is a android developing tool in the programming language C#.

I get the error on the classwhich is in this directory

**JeugdbewegingApp\JeugdbewegingApp\Presentation\MainMenu.cs**

In the following piece of code the error is thrown by the fragment class name.
This code is from the **NewsFeed.axml** layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="test" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" />
    <fragment
        class="jeugdbewegingApp/jeugdbewegingApp/presentation/MainMenu"
        android:id="@+id/menu_fragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I am aware of the namespace that needs to be written in lowercase but does your files and directories need to be in lowercase to?

I've been stuck for quite a while now and can't find a solution, the tutorial I am using is 
http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/fragments/part_1_-_creating_a_fragment/

The full error is this

> Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error
>   inflating class fragment   at
>   Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod
>   (intptr,intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) [0x00084] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.12-series/a1e3982a/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:895
>   at Android.App.Activity.SetContentView (int) [0x00070] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.12-series/a1e3982a/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-19/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:4252
>   at JeugdbewegingApp.NewsFeed.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) [0x00009] in
>   c:\Users\Jacob\Dropbox\2ICT\2de Semester\Projecten
>   1\Source\Jacob\JeugdbewegingApp\JeugdbewegingApp\Presentation\NewsFeed.cs:24
>   at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_
>   (intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00011] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.12-series/a1e3982a/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-19/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:2178
>   at at (wrapper dynamic-method)
>   object.08e9bb04-13ac-4397-9345-6bea3473292f (intptr,intptr,intptr)    at --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
>   at android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error
>   inflating class fragment   at at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
>   at at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
>   at at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>   at at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>   at at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
>   at at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
>   at at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)   at at
>   jeugdbewegingapp.NewsFeed.n_onCreate(Native Method)   at at
>   jeugdbewegingapp.NewsFeed.onCreate(NewsFeed.java:28)   at at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)   at at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>   at at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
>   at at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>   at at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>   at at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>   at at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)   at at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)   at at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)   at at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)   at at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)   at at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>   at at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)   at Caused by:
>   android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate
>   fragment jeugdbewegingapp/jeugdbewegingapp/presentation/MainMenu: make
>   sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that
>   is public   at at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:597) 
>   at at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:561)   at at
>   android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4778)   at at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
>   at ... 22 more   at Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   Didn't find class
>   "jeugdbewegingapp/jeugdbewegingapp/presentation/MainMenu" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/JeugdbewegingApp.JeugdbewegingApp-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/JeugdbewegingApp.JeugdbewegingApp-1,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]   at at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>   at at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)   at at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)   at at
>   android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:583)   at ... 25 more

If anyone could help me it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The class attribute should contain the full namespace of the class, not the path. As you've suggested, the namespace must be all lowercase as Java uses lowercase namespaces. The namespace in the wrapper class generated by Xamarin for your custom class will be lowercase. The actual class name will remain unchanged, and so doesn't need to be lowercase.

So, assuming your namespace is `JeugdbewegingApp.JeugdbewegingApp.Presentation.MainMenu`, your fragment xml should look like this...

```
<fragment
    class="jeugdbewegingapp.jeugdbewegingapp.presentation.MainMenu"
    android:id="@+id/menu_fragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I forgot to change the namespace of the fragment after i moved it to another directory...

Comment: What if you have '.' dot in you project name? Like Xamarin Forms projs 'Name.Droid'